# How do I modify this JavaScript to limit the entries to items in the data source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code, which works great, but I am relatively new to JavaScript(and jQuery) and I can't figure out how to only allow entries that are in the data source.

It currently lets you chose from the data source AND type in anything you want.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
  <input id="tags" size="50">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"**only allow entries that are in the data source**.
It currently lets you chose from the data source AND type in anything you want."* - If you want to implement this, first you should have all english alphabets in the data source, otherwise user will not be able to type anything at all, and no suggestions will be shown. Am I missing something..? You might want to rephrase your question to convey what exactly you have in mind.

Comment: @TJ No, that would be silly.  What I would like is that it would, `OnChang()`, check the data source and if none of the entries match remove them or notify the user.  Like this --> http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Why can't you use the code in example..?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend [_renderMenu](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderMenu) and limit the results that way.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/kqdL5jeh/2/

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];

    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }

    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }

    var auto = $("#tags")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
        .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
        },
        focus: function () {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
    }).data('ui-autocomplete');

    // render the menu, use itemLimit and change that :-D
    auto._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            itemLimit = 1;

        $.each(items, function (i, item) {
            if (i < itemLimit) self._renderItemData(ul, item);
        });
    };

});
```

Comment: okay, I think I see what you mean but I would now need combine this with my code, somehow, because this example only allows 1 entry.  Right?

Comment: Sure, give me a couple minutes.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin try it now. let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks for the help but this seems to do the same thing as mine, with the exception that only 1 suggestion appears in the dropdown....I was still able to type in anything I wanted....maybe I wasn't clear on my question or am I mistaken on your example?

Answer (score 0):

as the array is on client side , u can directly attach the onchange listener to the input box , and check the value of the input box with the array , if false display error , u may even suggest them based on the initial letters of the input .
Else use ajax request

Comment: My data source is only client side for my question as I thought it would simplify the question.  It is actually served up from a SQL DB internally.  Still, it SEEMS like you are saying I just need an `OnChange()` event and then check it against everything in my DB...no?